# CSV read specific row

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with 100 rows.

How do I read specific rows?

I want to read say the 9th line or the 23rd line etc?

Comment: How are you reading all the rows right now?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use a `list comprehension` to filter the file like so:

```
with open('file.csv') as fd:
    reader=csv.reader(fd)
    interestingrows=[row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx in (28,62)]
# now interestingrows contains the 28th and the 62th row after the header
```

Comment: How to read a single line. With below inputs is 
`interestingrows=[row for idx, row in enumerate(myreader) if idx in (28)]
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

Comment: for a single line, it's 
    interestingrows=[row for idx, row in  enumerate(myreader) if idx == 28]

Comment: Does this take non wanted rows in memory, while creating 'interestingrows' ?

Answer (score 20):

Use `list` to grab all the rows at once as a list. Then access your target rows by their index/offset in the list. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

with open('source.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    rows = list(csv_reader)

    print(rows[8])
    print(rows[22])
```

Answer (score 15):

You simply skip the necessary number of rows:

```
with open("test.csv", "rb") as infile:
    r = csv.reader(infile)
    for i in range(8): # count from 0 to 7
        next(r)     # and discard the rows
    row = next(r)   # "row" contains row number 9 now
```

Answer (score 5):

You could read all of them and then use normal lists to find them.

```
with open('bigfile.csv','rb') as longishfile:
    reader=csv.reader(longishfile)
    rows=[r for r in reader]
print row[9]
print row[88]
```

If you have a massive file, this can kill your memory but if the file's got less than 10,000 lines you shouldn't run into any big slowdowns.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
with open('raw_data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','))
    row_you_want = readCSV[index_of_row_you_want]
```

Comment: Yes but than you have the whole file in memory

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help you , using pandas you can easily do it with `loc`

```
'''
Reading 3rd record using pandas -> (loc)
Note : Index start from 0 
If want to read second record then 3-1 -> 2
loc[2]` -> read second row and `:` -> entire row details 
'''

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('employee_details.csv')
df.loc[[2],:]
```

**Output :**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("data.csv") as data_file:
    data = csv.reader(data_file)
    temperature = []
    for row in data:
        print(row[1])
```

I find this as a more simpler way if you are working with low amount of data.

Comment: you are printing the 2nd _column_ of each row. While potentially an interesting remark (not mentioned in the other answers yet), this is not what the OP asked for.