# How do you grab specific rows from csv file while avoiding others?

Tags: python, csv

Say I have 100 lines in a csv file.

However, I want rows 3-9 and 10-37.

Basically trying to skip certain rows. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my first answer I showed you how to get specific columns, my bad. I misread your question. In order to get specific rows, you can use list comprehension.

```
desired_row_indexes = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12] # You can also use ranges
desired_rows = [row for idx, row in enumerate(csv_document) if idx in desired_row_indexes]
```

This is actually [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464567/csv-read-specific-row)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the panda package to parse your CSV and skip specific row.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', skiprows='list with row number to skip')
```