# How to read from the 5th line in python csv module?

Tags: python

for some specific reason, I need to read from the 5th line of a csv file

but

```
reader=csv.reader(input_file)
df=[row for row in reader]
```

read the whole csv file, how to read from the 5th line?

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. My preferred way would be using pandas dataframe.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26464901/4516217