# How to resume reading a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for i in reader:
      print(i)
```

CSV

```
id,name
001,jane
002,winky
003,beli
...
```

So far the program will only read once the csv. The program will read from the first rows `001` if restart again. How could I resume the reading like example if the program stop reading at `002` then next start reading will be `003`?

Comment: You will have to save your progress in another file.

Comment: Which mean write the content into another file then next start to compare both files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV read specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464567/csv-read-specific-row)

Comment: The easiest would be save the amount of lines you've read already and skip this amount ahead at next start.

Comment: @mrHOT not a duplicate. Read the question first please.

Comment: I just wanna ask, what do you mean by restart, is it to quit the program by pressing crtl-c??

Comment: if you break the loop after say, 2 iterations, you'll see that looping again resumes reading, as the iterator isn't reset. Can you explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have the issue when the program suddenly run out of the memory of other unpredict situation cause to the program terminated. At this situation, I have to restart the program but I want it to resume the last row of record.

Comment: @kino.jom, if that's the issue, you can simply set a flag, when you reach n time of rows reading (like 500 row), you can let your program rest for a 4 seconds for exemple, it is only natural that your run out of memory if it is a big loop without timeout (sleep or rest time)

Comment: @MobrineHayde Thx...I will look for it.

Comment: How does the script know if it should resume reading or start from the beginning?

Comment: @MobrineHayde: Pausing the program won't affect the amount of memory it uses — only take it longer to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to continually save the current location in another file each time a row is read from the CSV file, which, of course, will add some overhead to processing it.

I think creating a [Context Manager Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) in conjunction with a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) statement would be a very good approach to use to solve this and will allow the overhead to be minimized to some degree.

The code below implements a content manager for reading CSV files and allows the reading of it or them to be automatically resumed if it's interrupted before the whole file has been read (within the context of the `with` statement).

This is done by creating a separate "state" file to keep track of the last row successfully read. This file will be deleted if no exception occurs while the reading is happening, however, it that won't happen and it will remain if one does. Because of that, the next time the file is read, the existing state file will be detected and used to allow the reading to start where it previously left off.

Notably, since each resumable CSV reader is a separate object, you can create and use more than one at a time. The associated "state" file for each one remains open while the CSV file is being read, so doesn't need to be repeatedly opened and closed each time its contents are updated.

```
import csv
import os

class ResumableCSVReader:

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.state_filename = filename + '.state'
        self.csvfile = None
        self.statefile = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.csvfile = open(self.filename, 'r', newline='')

        try:  # Open and read state file
            with open(self.state_filename, 'r', buffering=1) as statefile:
                self.start_row = int(statefile.read())

        except FileNotFoundError: # No existing state file.
            self.start_row = 0

        self.statefile = open(self.state_filename, 'w', buffering=1)

        return _CSVReaderContext(self)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.csvfile:
            self.csvfile.close()
        if self.statefile:
            self.statefile.close()
            if not exc_type:  # No exception?
                os.remove(self.state_filename) # Delete state file.


class _CSVReaderContext:

    def __init__(self, resumable):
        self.resumable = resumable
        self.reader = csv.reader(self.resumable.csvfile)

        # Skip to start row.
        for _ in range(self.resumable.start_row):
            next(self.reader)

        self.current_row = self.resumable.start_row

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.current_row += 1
        row = next(self.reader)

        # Update state file.
        self.resumable.statefile.seek(0)
        self.resumable.statefile.write(str(self.current_row)+'\n')

        return row


if __name__ == '__main__':

    csv_filename = 'resumable_data.csv'

    # Read a few rows and raise an exception.
    try:
        with ResumableCSVReader(csv_filename) as resumable:
            for _ in range(2):
                print('row:', next(resumable))

            raise MemoryError('Forced')  # Cause exception.

    except MemoryError:
        pass  # Expected, suppress to allow test to keep running.

    # CSV file is now closed.

    # Resume reading where left-off and continue to end of file.
    print('\nResume reading\n')

    with ResumableCSVReader(csv_filename) as resumable:
        for row in resumable:
            print('row:', row)

    print('\ndone')
```

Output:

```
row: ['id', 'name']
row: ['001', 'jane']

Resume reading

row: ['002', 'winky']
row: ['003', 'beli']

done
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to keep track of how far you've read the file as of now, `file.tell()` may come in handy. Afterwards you can start reading your file from here on using `file.seek()`.
The code would look somewhat like:

```
def read_from_position(last_position):
  file = open("file_location")
  file.seek(last_position)
  file.readline() # Do what you want with this
  return file.tell() # this is the updated last position
```

You can achieve the same in your code by keeping a track of how many lines you last read and iterating post that many number of lines.

Comment: `readline()` may do readahead and buffering behind the scenes, making `file.tell()` give results that don't necessarily match up with your readline progress.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to explicitly save the current location each time which may be a little bit computationally expensive, but it works and here is the code :

```
import csv


def update_last(x):
    with open('last.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(x))


def get_last():
    try:
        with open('last.txt', 'r') as file:
            return int(file.read().strip())
    except:
        with open('last.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write('0')
            return 0

with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    last = get_last() + 1
    current = 1
    for i in reader:
        if current < last:
            current += 1
            continue
        print(i)
        current += 1
        update_last(current)
```

Comment: `pathlib.Path.write_text` simplifies so much of this `open/write/close` stuff. And have your exception handler in `get_last` call `update_last(0)` - DRY!

Comment: @PaulMcG: The `Path.write_text()` method wasn't added until Python 3.5, so _not_ using it makes this code compatible with a larger number of versions...besides doing it the "old fashioned" way isn't too much more work in this particular case (IMO). (In fact, I'm a little surprised they even bothered adding as trivial as `write_text()` at all.)

Comment: mrHOT: FWIW, I think overall this is a sound approach—and your implementation certainly very succinct. That said, opening and closing the `last.txt` file every time a row is read is going to add a _lot_ of overhead, especially because it involves making multiple calls to the OS to do so (which tend to be very expensive). One suggestion I have would be to not hardcode the `last.txt` filename into it because doing so prevents the code from being used with more than one CSV file at a time. Also, additional code is needed to delete the file when it's no longer needed...

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic of generators:

```
def get_rows(infile='test.csv'):
    with open(infile) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield row

for id, name in get_rows():
    out = some_complex_business_logic(id, name)
    print(out)
```

The generator will pause while you run your complex business logic,
and then transparently resume when you're ready for the next row.